# Php MySQLi no errors but data doesn't Insert into table

Tags: php, mysqli

everything works,
except for the Insert statement (creatUser()) which returns no errors but the data doesn't get inserted.. all error handling checks out with the form, and the `emailTaken` function also works.

What am i doing wrong?

form:

```
</form>
        <form class="signup" action="includes/signUpManager.php" method="post">
          <div class="field">
            <input type="text" name='email' placeholder="Email Address" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <input type="password" name='pwd' placeholder="Password" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <input type="password" name='pwdRepeat' placeholder="Confirm password" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="field btn">
            <div class="btn-layer"></div>
            <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Sign up">
          </div>
        </form>
```

dbh.php:

```
<?php
$serverName = "127.0.0.1";
$dBUserName = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "Quiz1dB";

$conn = mysqli_connect($serverName, $dBUserName, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn){
    die("Connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

signUpManager.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    $pwdRepeat = $_POST['pwdRepeat'];

    require 'dbh.php';
    require 'functions.php';

    if (invalidEmail($email) !== false) {
        header("location:../index.php?error=invalidemail");
        exit(); 
    }
    if (pwdMatch($pwd, $pwdRepeat) !== false) {
    header("location:../index.php?error=passworddontmatch");
    exit(); 
    }
    if (emailTaken($conn, $email) !== false) {
        header("location:../index.php?error=emailtaken");
        exit(); 
    }

    creatUser($conn, $email, $pwd);

}
else{
    header("location:../index.php?error=elsebum");
    exit();
}
```

functions.php:

```
<?php

function invalidEmail($email){
    $result;
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $result = true;
    }
    else {
        $result = false;
    }

    return $result;

}

function pwdMatch($pwd, $pwdRepeat){
    $result;
    if ($pwd !== $pwdRepeat){
        $result = true;
    }
    else {
        $result = false;
    }

    return $result;

}
function emailTaken($conn, $email){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("location:../index.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {
        return $row;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
        return $result;
    }  
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}    

function creatUser($conn, $email, $pwd) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, userPassword) VALUES (?, ?);";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("location:../index.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }
    $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $hashedPwd);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    header("location:../index.php?error=none");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Make sure PHP error reporting is on, and mysqli error handling is on. See these setup guides for how to do that: https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/ (php error logging/reporting)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14578644/5947043 (mysqli error handling)
 . Then test it again and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson, So there's nothing overtly wrong with the code i posted ?

Comment: There's plenty of things wrong with this code, but you have to be more specific

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439) Once you enable mysqli error reporting please update the question with the error message.

Comment: 1. Enable mysqli error reporting 2. Remove all the `if` statements around mysqli functions. 3. `pwdMatch()` function is useless, it is just an if statement. 4. The same with `invalidEmail()`. Just do a normal `if` statement. 5. `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);` in `emailTaken()` is NOOP code. Remove it. 6. There is absolutely no reason to call `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);` right before `exit`.

Comment: You put that line right before `mysqli_connect` and then you can remove all `if` statements. See how it is done in the manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: @Dharman, thank you! I keep writing comments and you answer them before i post..So i'll update the code and report back. Thanks again!

Comment: Nah don't add an answer. If that line helped to solve the problem then let's use that as an answer instead. I am glad that I was able to help.